# StringUtils StripAccents replaces accented letters with question marks

Tags: java, scala, apache-stringutils

I'm trying to use [Apache StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) stripAccents() method to remove accents from characters, and isntead of doing that it outputs question marks in place of accented letters.

Example: `Ádám` is converted to `?dam` instead of `Adam`. I'm using Scala version 2.12.3

Has anybody had this issue?

Comment: Hi! Could you please share sample code demonstrating this behaviour?

Comment: I tried it locally. Works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Check codepage on every file/reader operation etc. It is UTF-8 or national codepage? Non-eglish programming has such difficulties

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for replying. I didn't recieve any emails about notification and didn't check. The code where I use it is a bit messy but when I open a blank REPL worksheet and run `Ádám.stripAccents` It gets outputed with question marks. There might be a problem with build dependencies, I'll probably need a coworker's help. Just wanted to know if anyone had experienced it and solved it somehow